# How to delete Matlab drive connector

Tags: macos, matlab

I installed an app, called Matlab drive connector, however, I cannot uninstall it.

I tried to uninstall in the Applications, however, I even did not find this app.

I also read this tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlabdrive/ug/install-matlab-drive.html  however, I did not find "Mathworks" in the path mentioned in the tutorial, so I failed to delete it.

This App just pops out every time I restart the Mac, it is really annoying.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the `~` at the beginning of the path in the `cd` command in the tutorial at that link? Anyway, I would ask this question on the MATLAB forum. Do specify which version of MATLAB and macOS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your Login items:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Make sure your User Account is selected at top left
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Look for an item called *Matlab drive connector* (or something similar that could be triggering this) in the list of login items
5. Now remove this item by clicking on its name (so it's highlighted) and then clicking on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button
6. Once it's removed, exit System Preferences
7. Restart your Mac to test to see if the problem still persists